# Create a custom Tokenizer in Solr 5.x

Tags: solr

How can we create a Custom Tokenizer in Solr 5.x ? I want to add my own tokenizer class instead of using StandardTokenizerFactory, WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory etc

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the existing tokenizers. I just wanted to know how we could configure solr to introduce a new custom Tokenizer. I have looked at pages which talk about creating a custom solr filter(http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/), but I could not find anything about creating a custom Solr Tokenizer

Comment: It's the same procedure. Just reference your own tokenizer in the schema instead - the lib dir etc. will be the same.